# Oracle tables (for user SYSTEM) are not displayed in Azure Data Factory's Table names dropdown menu

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data from Oracle database table to MS SQL database using Azure Data Factory pipeline.

I have installed oracle locally and using the SYSTEM user, I have created couple of tables in oracle as seen in the screenshot below: [image]

After connecting this local oracle instance with Azure Data Factory via Self Hosted Runtime, I am unable to see the names of these tables in the dropdown of Table names list while creating a dataset for one of these tables. Below are the screenshots of what I am trying to achieve:
[image: You can see the table names Azure data factory fetched from ORACLE]
But when I search for these tables `SPENDREPORT` and `SPENDREPORTDETAILS`, they are not found in this dropdown, as shown in the screenshot below. Any clues as to how I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: Oracle strongly recommends that you not create objects in the `sys` or `system` schemas.  You really ought to create a new user (and thus a new schema) to own any objects you want to create.  I don't know whether it is possible to tell Azure Data Factory not to filter out `system` objects (which is a very sensible default).  But you're likely to be happier all around if you structure things in the expected way.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Justin Cave and also as per Oracle [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5.htm#ADMQS12003) You must not create any tables in the SYS schema.

•**SYS**

This account can perform all administrative functions. All base (underlying) tables and views for the database data dictionary are stored in the SYS schema. These base tables and views are critical for the operation of Oracle Database. To maintain the integrity of the data dictionary, tables in the SYS schema are manipulated only by the database. They should never be modified by any user or database administrator. You must not create any tables in the SYS schema.
The SYS user is granted the SYSDBA privilege, which enables a user to perform high-level administrative tasks such as backup and recovery.

•   **SYSTEM**

This account can perform all administrative functions except the following:

•   Backup and recovery

•   Database upgrade

You should also try to clear Data factory cache and then refresh Table name field.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle tables with $ in them are system tables for Oracle itself. Oracle uses them for its own specific reasons and they will not have any meaning in other RDBMSses like SQL Server.
Trying to use the $ tables is usually a sign you are going the wrong way. If you ever need to refer to the objects (tables, views) you should use the proper metadata views Oracle provides or use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Because they are internal tables they can also change or disappear in the next version or patch. Your applications / queries might break if you use em. DO NOT USE THEM, IF YOU DO IT WILL COST YOU $$$$$ IN THE END WHEN THINGS GO WRONG. You certainly dont need to port this (internal dollar tables).

You are looking for the tables to port that make YOUR application work. The rest is irrelvant.

Also, some "clever" guys might look at how Oracle handles it's meta data (meant for small amounts of data only) and build their own application just like that. This usually ends up with bad performance and a lot of other issues. See for example EAV schema like it is described with all its pitfalls in Bill Karwin's excellent book SQL Antipatterns

Answer (score 0):

As already specified in the answer above you should not create any table in the SYS schema rather create a new user using.

```
CREATE USER 'username' IDENTIFIED BY 'user' PASSWORD 'password';
```

and grant the required privileges like tablespace etc to it.

```
GRANT CONNECT TO 'user';
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO 'user';
```

Now the tables created inside this schema will be visible to you in ADF.